# Relating to multiple possessions of multiple objects

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say `doctors specialties` when referring to the (multiple) specialties of multiple doctors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possessive plural would be `doctors' specialties`, meaning many doctors having specialties.  It would be ambiguous whether each doctor had one specialty or more than one.  One doctor having many specialties would be `doctor's specialties`.  While I was writing this, MT_Head provided a nice link to the Chicago style manual that should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You would write "doctors' specialties."

Here's the Chicago Manual of Style's free sample Q&A on multiple possessives:
http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/PossessivesandAttributives/PossessivesandAttributives08.html

Specifically, this phrase: "It’s always correct to form the plural possessive with an apostrophe"

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as **the specialty of doctors** which would make it very clear to the reader.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer the question and by the way should't "specialty" be in plural when referring to multiple specialties?